# How do I check if the left angle bracket key is pressed?

Tags: java, keyboard, keycode

In Java, I have checked the list of Virtual Key Codes, and there is not a VK for '<'. I have tried "VK_LESS" with my program (which sounds like it could be '<'), but that did not work either.

I am wondering if I have to check to see if the Shift key is pressed down, and then check to see if the Comma key is also pressed down, but I am not sure how to do that in a KeyHandler class, using a switch statement for the keyPressed method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KeyHandler `keyPressed` method will receive a `KeyEvent`. You can call `isShiftDown()` on that `KeyEvent` to see if the shift key is currently pressed.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_COMMA && e.isShiftDown()) {
         // do your thing!
    }
}
```

You could also try doing:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyChar() == '<') {  
         ...
    }
}
```

Note the use of `keyTyped` rather than `keyPressed`. `keyTyped` triggers only when a key press outputs a character, rather than on every key press. This method would be more likely to work for other types of keyboard. But I haven't tried it, so I don't know if it would work at all.

Comment: Does that work on all keyboard layouts, or just QWERTY?

Comment: @aryn.galadar you're right, the `keyPressed` suggestion would only detect `<` specifically on keyboards where `shift` + `comma` == `<`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd want to use VK_LESS and VK_GREATER for "<" and ">", respectively.

Comment: I think this would only be relevant for a keyboard with a real `<` key, if that exists. On a QWERTY keyboard, the listener will report `comma` + `shift`.

Comment: There is a demo key listener in the java tutorial pages if you want to try: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/uiswing/KeyEventDemoProject/KeyEventDemo.jnlp

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyEvents.getKeyChar() method

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (evt.getKeyChar().equals("<")) {
         /*your code*/
    }
}
```

Comment: From the docs: _Character input is reported by KEY_TYPED events: KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events are not necessarily associated with character input. Therefore, the result of the getKeyChar method is guaranteed to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED events._